# WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document

Tags: python-sphinx, toctree

I'm using sphinx for documenting my Django application.

I have the following directory structure of docs

```
docs
|- build
|- source
   |- _static
   |- _templates
   |- conf.py
   |- index.rst
   |- upgrade.rst
|- upgrade_changes
   |- migration
      |- index.rst
   |- index.rst
   |- library_changes.rst
```

and the content of `docs/source/index.rst` is

```
My App's documentation!
=============================================
App Description

Revamp Upgrade Changes
----------------------

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   upgrade
```

the `source/upgrade.rst` file inludes the content from `upgrade_changes`

```
.. include:: ../upgrade_changes/index.rst
```

And the `/upgrade_changes/index.rst` has

```
Following is the list of all revamp related documentation.

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   library_changes
```

I want to include a **toctree** for the `library_changes.rst` file which is at the same level os of `index.rst`.

But this gives an error

```
upgrade_changes/index.rst:50: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'library_changes'
```

**How can I include the files to toctree at the same level?**